# What format/ class/ UI/ file data structure should I use to read text and write "favorites" data?

Tags: iphone, ios, file, text

I'm new to iphone/ ios programming. I'm developing a simple app to display formatted text (italic, bold, underline, tab space). What should I use?

1) Store the text in core data, SQL, or files?

2) Code the text in xml and parse it (below)? Or, is there another way, just copy and paste from MS Word? Or do I use UIWebView?

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"event" ofType:@"xml"];
```

3) What's an easy way to mark a page "favorite" so that I can retrieve those pages easily?

4) For "favorite" pages, do I store the info in core data, SQL, or write to files?

Thanks in advance for taking the time to answer these basic questions.

PS: Sad day as we lost a great biz/ tech genius. Could only delve on what Steve Jobs said ... there will be a renewal, a make way for the next biz / tech genius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answers per question:
1) better is files, and don't forget using amazing UIDocument api from apple
2) u don't need to to conversation to xml or other (like world :), just save as rtfd format
3) better is a save in NSUserDefaults dictionary with file name and page numbers as favorite
4) answered before

Comment: user170317 thanks. If I use rtfd format for my file, after I read into my app, could I easily change toggle the text color and bkgnd color from white/ black to black/ white? How do I do that?

Comment: please review nsattributedstring api - u can upload rtfd into attributed string and change anything what u want...